# SIMD _mm_store_si128 | _mm_storeu_si128 don't storing correctly

Tags: c++, simd, intrinsics, instruction-set

I have a string

```
const signed char From[] = {
    0b00000000, 0b00000001, 0b00000010, 0b00000011,
    0b00000100, 0b00000101, 0b00000110, 0b00000111,
    0b00001000, 0b00001001, 0b00001010, 0b00001011,
    0b00001100, 0b00001101, 0b00001110, 0b00001111,
};
```

i need to place chars from this string into a __m128i vector and than store bytes from this vector into a `std::uint32_t Schedule[4]` array

Doing this:

```
const __m128i Chars = _mm_set_epi8 (
    From[0],
    From[1],
    From[2],
    From[3],
    From[4],
    From[5],
    From[6],
    From[7],
    From[8],
    From[9],
    From[10],
    From[11],
    From[12],
    From[13],
    From[14],
    From[15]
);
```

And now store this vector into Schedule:

```
_mm_store_si128((__m128i*)&Schedule[Kter], SettedLines4);
```

And we have incorrect Byte order in Schedule(also i think this is not an incorrect byte order. I think bits were mixed)

```
template<typename Type>
[[ nodiscard ]] std::string to_binary(Type Data) noexcept
{
    std::string Result = "";

    std::uint64_t CurrentBit = 8 * sizeof Data;
    while(CurrentBit--)
        Result += ((Data >> CurrentBit) & 1) == 0 ? "0" : "1";

    return Result;
}

std::cout << to_binary(Schedule[0]) << std::endl;
std::cout << to_binary(Schedule[1]) << std::endl;
std::cout << to_binary(Schedule[2]) << std::endl;
std::cout << to_binary(Schedule[3]) << std::endl;
```

Full code:

```
# include <x86intrin.h>
# include <iostream>
# include <cstdint>

template<typename Type>
[[ nodiscard ]] std::string to_binary(Type Data) noexcept
{
    std::string Result = "";

    std::uint64_t CurrentBit = 8 * sizeof Data;
    while(CurrentBit--)
        Result += ((Data >> CurrentBit) & 1) == 0 ? "0" : "1";

    return Result;
}

int main(void)
{
    std::uint32_t Schedule[4];
    const signed char From[] = {
        0b00000000, 0b00000001, 0b00000010, 0b00000011,
        0b00000100, 0b00000101, 0b00000110, 0b00000111,
        0b00001000, 0b00001001, 0b00001010, 0b00001011,
        0b00001100, 0b00001101, 0b00001110, 0b00001111,
    };

    const __m128i v = _mm_set_epi8 (
        From[0],
        From[1],
        From[2],
        From[3],
        From[4],
        From[5],
        From[6],
        From[7],
        From[8],
        From[9],
        From[10],
        From[11],
        From[12],
        From[13],
        From[14],
        From[15]
    );

    _mm_store_si128((__m128i*)&Schedule[0], v);
    std::cout << to_binary(Schedule[0]) << std::endl;
    std::cout << to_binary(Schedule[1]) << std::endl;
    std::cout << to_binary(Schedule[2]) << std::endl;
    std::cout << to_binary(Schedule[0]) << std::endl;
}
```

How can i fix it? I need to get the same byte order as expected

Comment: What is the output of your code? What do you expect it to be?

Comment: The output is:

```00001100000011010000111000001111
00001000000010010000101000001011
00000100000001010000011000000111
00001100000011010000111000001111```

I want it to be:
```00000000000000010000001000000011
00000100000001010000011000000111
00001000000010010000101000001011
00001100000011010000111000001111```

The awaited output is in order as in From

(im sorry, i dont how to place endlines here)

Comment: I have an idea that it was happened because invalid casting (__m128i*)&Schedule[0] in _mm_store_si128 arg but i still have no idea how to fix it

Comment: @faust403, the casting is ok. Although it appears to violate Strict Aliasing Rule, for load/store intrinsics it is ok to do such casts, because these intrinsics are designed for such usage. Just be sure to align the destination variable properly, or use unaligned store.

Comment: Please [edit] clarifications into the question rather than adding them in the comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that `_mm_set_epi8` takes parameters starting from most significant. You need `_mm_setr_epi8` or reverse parameters order

Also you have a typo:

```
    std::cout << to_binary(Schedule[0]) << std::endl;
    std::cout << to_binary(Schedule[1]) << std::endl;
    std::cout << to_binary(Schedule[2]) << std::endl;
    std::cout << to_binary(Schedule[0]) << std::endl;
```

The last is `0`.

Also it is an error to use `_mm_store_si128` for not properly aligned destination. This may or may not crash. Use `_mm_storeu_si128` or align your destination by 16.

Comment: Yeah, but the last(or first, idk) line is still invalid

Comment: i added spaces for the best view. 
 ```00000011 00000010 00000001 00000000
 00000111 00000110 00000101 00000100
 00001011 00001010 00001001 00001000
 00000011 00000010 00000001 00000000```

As you can see, last line repeats first(or vice versa)

Comment: @faust403, this is because you repeat the last index. Your indices are `0`, `1`, `2`, `0`.

Comment: Ah, yeah, you are right, Sorry for my mistake

Also the right order is

From[12],
From[13],
From[14],
From[15],
From[8],
From[9],
From[10],
From[11],
From[4],
From[5],
From[6],
From[7],
From[0],
From[1],
From[2],
From[3]

Comment: @faust403: So you're reversing bytes within each dword, like endian conversion?  You can do that with a constant for `_mm_shuffle_epi8`.  Your source *might* be getting optimized to a `pshufb` instruction, but a clearer way to write it would be with vector loads/stores like `_mm_loadu_si128( (const __m128i*)From)` and `_mm_storeu_si128( (__m128i*)schedule, v)`, where `v` comes from a shuffle.  Or if you're reversing dwords in groups of 4 but keeping bytes in the same order within 4-byte groups, use `_mm_shuffle_epi32(v, _MM_SHUFFLE(0,1,2,3))`